# Twilio API for Average Handling Time, Number of Calls attended, CSAT etc

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there an API in Twilio for Agent metrics i.e Average Handling Time, Number of Calls attended, CSAT etc of the agent that is logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The only [API for Flex Insights is the API to export reports](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/insights/api/export-data).

Comment: Can we not calculate the Average Handling Time of an agent without using insights? Is there a way using taskrouter or worker statistics?

Comment: Oh, sure, in that case you are looking for the [worker statistics resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker/statistics) and the [task queue statistics resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/taskqueue-statistics).